# How to make an Alpha Gradient Mask?

Tags: javafx, computer-vision

i'm trying to make something like that : 
[Alpha Gradient Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W7Qy.jpg) using javafx

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will notice pretty quickly that this type of questions will not yield very good answers. You should try to do it your self first. And then when you get stuck, you can come back with more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not looking for a complete solution, juste a few ideas like which functions should i use to achieve this.

Comment: Similar to: [Create an image-overlay mask in javafx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170383/create-an-image-overlay-mask-in-javafx)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it with the "AlphaComposite" function.

Here is my code :

```
private Image mask;
private Image dest;
private float alpha = 1f;

private void loadImages() {

    mask = new ImageIcon("resources/source.png").getImage();
    dest = new ImageIcon("resources/destination.png").getImage();
}

private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

    BufferedImage buffImg = new BufferedImage(500, 400,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D gbi = buffImg.createGraphics();

    AlphaComposite ac = AlphaComposite.getInstance(
            AlphaComposite.SRC_IN, alpha);

    gbi.drawImage(mask, 0, 0, null);
    gbi.setComposite(ac);
    gbi.drawImage(dest, 0, 0, null);

    g2d.drawImage(buffImg, 20, 20, null);

    gbi.dispose();
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

Here is what i get :

[Original image & Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HawCT.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbs60.png)

I would like to do the same thing in Javafx because i'm working with Javafx images (or Mat images from OPENCV Library).