# How do I add two images, one above the other to a shape in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

Please help.

I am trying to add two images to the shape:

```
@FXML
private Rectangle rectangle;
Image img1 = new Image("a.png");
Image img2 = new Image("b.png");
rectangle.setFill(new ImagePattern(img1));
rectangle.setFill(new ImagePattern(img2));
```

Images have a transparent background. Both should be visible. One above the other.

But only one is visible.

How to correctly add images?

I will be grateful for the advice.

**UPDATE**

application functionality:

1. Generate the given number of shapes
2. Click the shape (square) to open a dialog
3. The dialogue shows images
4. You mark the selected images from the dialog
5. You add selected images to the shape (square)

Comment: maybe it could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080523/how-to-blend-two-image-in-javafx

Comment: I need to set several images. But I can not use getChildren().addAll

Comment: Only one is visible, because `setFill` replace old value

Comment: A shape can only have a single fill and you cannot combine multiple paints to a single one. This means for this to be possible you'd need to create a single image containing the content from both images. I wouldn't recommend doing this though: simply use a `VBox` with 2 `ImageView`s as children.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to change it. But it fails.

Comment: something wrong in the code you are not showing? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Others already said that `Shape` can only have one fill, so only one image is shown, what you can do is use `StackPane` which put elements one over another, depending on what you want to achieve you might not need to use `Rectangle` at all.

You can setup `BlendMode` on `ImageView` to change the way they blend up.

For example:

```
    StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
    Image img1 = new Image("a.png");
    Image img2 = new Image("b.png");
    stackPane.getChildren().addAll(new ImageView(img1), new ImageView(img2));
```

Comment: I know that. In this case, using Pane as other containers will give the same result.  But I can not use getChildren().addAll

Comment: What is reason that you can't use `addAll`?